# Backing up and restoring Redis on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, redis

I'm running an app on Heroku that uses Redis and Postgres.

Occasionally I backup and restore postgres to a lower tier like `staging` or `development` to do some testing.

Is there a similar inbuilt redis tool to backup from a production instance and restore to a local instance? I could write something that loops through each key and outputs it to file, and then something else that locally reads from that file and restores, but I feel like that might be overkill if a utility already exists to do that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Redis can dump the date to a disk file using a format called RDB. You should check with your Redis provider how to generate and obtain these files.